# google maps API with internal and external users

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i recently built a google map on our company portal to display pins for all locations where we did construction work. all connections from our office load the map markers just fine but everyone outside the office never load the pins, however the map itself loads just fine.

the marker location source is a SQL server db located on Azure and the site is aspx hosted in the office. the entire portal site has no other issues for external users with any other features.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: not even remotely possible or i would have. the thing plots points from our database. all i could put here is page code, but thats obviously not the issue.